# Using twitter bootstrap rails in an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm currently trying to develop a rails engine and i would like to use twitter boostrap rails  in this engine. I've already added the gem to my dependencies in the gemspec file but there's rails generators that  need to be executed to run properly . How could i run the twitter boostrap generators automatically when the engine is installed ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your own generator, you can execute a command line like this :

```
...
`rails g bootstrap:install`
...
```

Don't forget the `.

Not sure but you can also try this :

```
generator = Bootstrap::Generators::InstallGenerator.new
generator.add_assets
generator.add_bootstrap
generator.cleanup_legacy
```

I think the better way is this :

```
Rails::Generators.invoke "bootstrap:install", [], :behavior => :invoke, :destination_root => Rails.root
```

Comment: Where should i place this code to be executed only one time at the installation of the engine ? Do i have to create myself a generator or is an another way

Comment: ok the last option in your response did the trick perfectly !! thanks